# Rails/Laravel ecosystem equivalent in Javascript/NodeJS ecosystem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, laravel

In my current projects, when I need to create some web system (a web MVC system, with so many CRUDs) I used to build it with:

Rails + ActiveRecord + Devise + Carrierwave + other libraries

or

Laravel + Eloquent ORM + other libraries

I started to study Javascript/ES6/Typescript and a lot of other things, and I want to create some "clone" of a system that I made previously in Rails or Laravel, and build it with Javascript.

What stack technology is equivalent/similar to Rails ecosystem or Laravel ecosystem (both are MVC web framework)?
I hear about Meteor, Adonis, Express, but I am much confused about which of these is really a web MVC framework, and what is the main cases of uses of each one of them. I read many blog posts, and I am still confused about that.

My goal is to build a web MVC system, with many CRUDs.

What do you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most used JS stack is the MEAN stack: MongoDB, Express, Angular, and Node.
You can find two popular frameworks  here:

- [mean.io](http://mean.io)
- [meanjs.org](http://meanjs.org)

Of course you have alternatives and variations like using React in place of Angular an many more.

Sure you'll find tons of useful information searching about "mean stack".

Good look and enjoy learning them!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an all in one solution similar to Laravel or Rails that I'd personally advocate for. However, one framework I've kept my eye on and use in production within my organization is https://nestjs.com/, which *doesn't* include everything you'd need for a typical MVC app, but does have a set of nice conveniences for building an API including an ORM and a dependency injection container (Angular's). So you have the M and C, choose your templating engine of choice for the V.